# how to add sides of shape in python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm a newbie in python so please bear with me. I was making a program that draws a turtle shape using OOP and I'm running into some issues. The first issue I had is in my drawShape method I am required to draw a shape with the sides and length of my argument. It can be any regular shape so I chose square but I used t.forward inserting d as the length of the shape how can I add s as the side of my shape to draw it as required. The second issue I had is in my `__str__` method I wanted to return the current state of my turtle position I used turtle.pos to return the position but how do I also include the current heading of the turtle. I added comments on what I'm trying to do all over my code to make it easier to understand my code. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import turtle
import random

class Terrapin:

    #list of 5 color names
    colors = ["green", "yello", "red", "blue", "black"]
    
    def __init__(self, win, tur, x, y, dir, color, width):
        #win: The turtle screen/window. In __init__, create the window
        self.win = win
        #tur:  The turtle object itself. In __init__,
        #create a turtle and store it in this attribute
        self.tur = tur
        #current x location of the Turtle. Initialize to 0
        self.x = x
        #Current y location of the Turtle. Initialize to 0
        self.y = y
        #Current heading of the Turtle (angle). Initialize to 0
        self.dir = dir
        #Current color of the Turtle. Pick a random value from colors,
        #and set the Turtle to that color
        self.color = color
        #Current width of the Turtle. Pick a random value from 1 to 5,
        #and set the Turtle's width to that value
        self.width = width
        x = 0
        y = 0
        dir = 0
        color = random.choice(colors)
        width = randint(1, 5)
    
    def updateLoc(self, newX, newY, newDir):
        #Without drawing a line, move the Turtle to newX, 
        #newY,facing newDir.
        #Update self.x, self.y, and self.dir to the new values
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(newX, newY)
        setheading(newDir)
        self.x = newX
        self.y = newY
        self.dir = newDir
        
        
    def whereAmI(self):
        #Return a tuple of x, y, and dir.
        return ("x", "y", "dir")
    
    def drawShape(self, s, d):
        #Draw a regular shape with "s" sides of length "d", starting at x, y, dir.
        #Leave the Turtle pointing in the direction it started
        #(i.e. self.dir at the end must equal self.dir at that start).
        #Regular means equal length sides, like a triangle, square, hexagon, etc.
        startPos = turtle.setworldcoordinates(x, y, dir)
        turtle.setworldcoordinates(x, y, dir)
        turtle.forward(d)
        t.left(90)
        turtle.forward(d)
        t.left(90)
        turtle.forward(d)
        t.left(90)
        turtle.forward(d)
        t.left(90)
        setheading(startPos)
        
    def setWidth(self, w):
        #Set the Turtle's width to w, and save in self.width.
        self.width = w
    
    def newColor(self):
        #Set the Turtle's color to a new random value, and save in self.color.
        newColor = turtle.pencolor(random.choice(colors))
        turtle.pencolor(random.choice(colors))
        self.color = newColor
        
    
    def __str__(self):
        #Returns the current turtle state as "x, y @ dir"
        #If the Turtle is at 10, 100 with a heading of 270, this will print "10, 100 @ 270"
        turtle.pos()
    
doug = Terrapin()
doug.drawShape(4, 200)   # Draws a rectangle
doug.newColor()
doug.setWidth(4)
doug.drawShape(5, 100)   # Draws a pentagram
doug.updateLoc(100, 50, 0)
doug.drawShape(3, 50)
print(doug)
```

Comment: Make up your mind: does the object creation require those seven values, or not?  You control the class definition -- Python simply requires you to make consistent decisions in your communication.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.  This post has three questions, and more problems underneath; this violates the "one issue" requirement of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't an OOP tutorial website, there is no bug with your code at all. You just need to edit your code according to your needs.

Comment: You are still asking for open-ended, personal tutorial help on multiple issues.  As we've already pointed out, each of these violates the Stack Overflow posting guidelines.  Also check [can someone help me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This suggests a range of needs too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this

```
doug = Terrapin(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

But more broadly...

If you aren't sure what values you want to use, you probably need to think about what you program is going to do before you make it.

You look like you're using Turtle graphics, i would try to play around with that library before you make any object oriented stuff

UPDATED

"The first issue I had is in my drawShape method I am required to draw a shape with the sides and length of my argument. It can be any regular shape so I chose square but I used t.forward inserting d as the length of the shape how can I add s as the side of my shape to draw it as required."

This sounds like homework lol

I think you are talking about Equilateral polygons.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy39S.png

So the sum of interior angles is (n-2)*180

So a single interior angle is (n-2)*180/n

So and then the angle to move for a d sided polygon is

180 - (d-2)*180/d

EI 4 sided square

180-(4-2)*180/4 = 90

"The second issue I had is in my **str** method I wanted to return the current state of my turtle position I used turtle.pos to return the position but how do I also include the current heading of the turtle."

So decide if you want to print or return this.
I think you probably want to print.

```
print(x,", ",y," @ ",direction)
```

Note that dir is highlighted differently because it means something else and you cannot use it as a variable

Comment: I updated my question. My first question was not we explained but I figured it out. Please review my updated question. Thanks @6UvNtndXsv